# Increasing nesting in sub headings with LaTeX

Tags: latex

The following is an example of what I currently have:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\chapter{The Chapter}

\section{First Section}
\subsection{First sub Section}
\subsubsection{First sub sub Section}
```

which renders something like this:

```
Chapter 1
The Chapter

1.1 First Section
1.1.1 First Sub Section
1.1.1.1 First sub sub Section
```

---

Now unfortunately in LaTeX, I can only go down to a `subsubsection` (`1.1.1.1`) but I need to be able to go down further...for example, something like this `1.1.2.1.3`.  Are there any commands that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
```

Then you can get two more levels by using `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph`. For even more levels you need to extend standard LaTeX's sectioning mechanism. It's not actually difficult, just tedious to do.

Answer (score 3):

even further, with the book class you have:

```
part
chapter
section
subsection
subsubsection
paragraph
subparagraph
```

and if that's not good, I whipped up this .sty file a little while ago:

http://gist.github.com/raw/217934/9c391f6718ade897defa18bf8c504682a7d2d655/subsections.sty